# php_ffmpeg module not loading in Windows 7

Tags: php, ffmpeg

PLEASE help me! I have been searching for solutions for days!

I am running Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.21 on Windows 7.

I have extracted and copied php_ffmpeg.dll to C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext; copied avcodex-51.dll, avformat-51.dll, avutil-49.dll and pthreadGC2.dll to C:\Windows\System32; and added the extension=php_ffmpeg.dll directive to php.ini. However, the module is still not loading.

I found the following error in the PHP error log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_ffmpeg.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

Any help would be dearly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your windows is 64bit you have to copy

"avcodex-51.dll/ avformat-51.dll/ avutil-49.dll/ pthreadGC2.dll"

to C:\Windows\SysWOW64